# Converting primitive arrays to String during Reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working on a toString method for reflection.
Currently I can handle all primitive types with the following code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Field field;
    String value;
    try {
        for (String FIELDS1 : FIELDS) {
            field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(FIELDS1.toLowerCase());
            value = field.get(this).toString();
            result.append("\n").append(field.getName())
                    .append("[").append(field.getType().getName()).append("]")
                    .append(" : ")
                    .append(value)
                    .append(",");
        }
        return result.toString().substring(0, result.length()-1);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException 
            | SecurityException 
            | IllegalArgumentException 
            | IllegalAccessException  ex) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

However, as soon as the method encounters an array of primitive types it does not print the entire array, I completely understand why.
To solve this I created methods that convert arrays of primitive types to a String and is called via `java.lang.reflect.Method` and invoked:

```
if(field.getType().isArray() && field.getType().getName().contains("String"))
{
    method = this.getClass().getMethod("stringArrToString", String[].class);
    value = method.invoke(this, field.get(this)).toString();
}
else
{
    value = field.get(this).toString();
}


public String stringArrToString(String[] array){
    return Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

I'm passing an Object and cannot cast the object when passing it can anyone provide me with some insight into solving this problem generically? I want to stay away from libraries for now as I want to gain a better understanding of reflection.

Comment: And why don't you post the one method that your question is about? Why giving us 5 lines of descriptive **text**, but not the source code?

Comment: @GhostCat I already changed so much of my code when I posted. I posted more or less what I did. I know it is not the correct way of doing it, that is why I need some help.

Comment: Although I didn't fully understand the question, the second code snippet looks dubious. Why are you obtaining a method and calling it with `method.invoke`, when you could just *call* it directly?